# How can I change a css element on my angular 7 website based on result for a url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular7

I have a few sonoff tasmotas and I am making a Web control panel for them. If I go to http://sonoff/cmnd?cmnd=Power (or something like that) it will respond with {"power": "on"} or {"power": "off"}. How can I change what css classes are applied to an html object based on the response from this. I also need it to change when I manually press the button on the sonoff without reloading the page.

Any help will be much appreciated

I am a total noob, I made a new project using `ng new PrinterPanel --routing` and haven't changed the structure much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add a code snippet to help understand your problem better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that the calls to the URLs are made from a controller / service.
If that is the case you probably have some functions you are calling on the click and other events, perhaps something like this will work for you:

```
<span ng-class="styleFunction('Power')">some text</span>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.styleFunction = function(param){

$http.get(http://sonoff/cmnd?cmnd=" + param)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response[param] === 'on')
        return "ClassOn";
    else
        return "ClassOff";
  });    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Oops, I'm using angular 7 not angularjs, I forgot about that, sorry for not being specific. I've just gotten into angular.

Comment: If that is the case just the fuction should be in the component typescript file and in the html change it to [ngClass]